# Is there any better way to update view then using setter methods

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

I am using Spring with Hibernate.
There is a checkbox sign (unicode) in my view, which I turn checked (just a diffrente unicode) with executePhase function like below:

```
public void executePhase(int phase, int lp) {

    OrderItemDto orderItemByLpView = this.getOrderItemByLp(lp);
    if (orderItemByLpView != null) {

        orderItemByLpView = ordersService.executePhase(phase, orderItemByLpView, sessionBean.getUser());

            return;
        }
    }
```

My view xhtml code:

```
...
<p:column>
    <p:commandLink value="\u2610" 
                   actionListener="#{this.executePhase(3, item.lp)}"
                   update=":contentForm:productionPlan" 
                   rendered="#{empty item.phase3DateTime}">
        <p:confirm header="bla" message="bla bla" icon="ui-icon-alert" />
    </p:commandLink>
</p:column>
...
```

The problem is that if I turn it on with commandLink button it will not refresh it without F5, unless I use setters like:

```
orderItemByLpView.setPhase1DateTime(orderItemByLpView.getPhase1DateTime());
orderItemByLpView.setPhase2DateTime(orderItemByLpView.getPhase2DateTime());
orderItemByLpView.setPhase3DateTime(orderItemByLpView.getPhase3DateTime());
orderItemByLpView.setPhase1User(orderItemByLpView.getPhase1User());
orderItemByLpView.setPhase2User(orderItemByLpView.getPhase2User());
orderItemByLpView.setPhase3User(orderItemByLpView.getPhase3User());
```

As you can see setters looks ugly. Is there any better way? Like doing whatever it is doing in the background on those lines?

Comment: No, I cannot see the setters look ugly. And the 'setters' I see have no relation whatsover with jsf or PrimeFaces. For me, effectively this question is totally unclear (e.g. the relation with the refresh problem you describe)...

Comment: If the action or action listener modifies the view model you kind of should updat them via the setters... Anything else would just be confusing and unclear. I don't understand the problem here.

Comment: Oh I didn't give enough info. Let me edit.

Comment: Still totally unclear to me, sorry

Comment: Please notice - orderItemByLpView setters using itself to set its values. That is my problem. If I don't do it - it will not update the view. I admit I am beginner in JAVA but this looks crazy, isn't it?

Comment: I guess somewhere Spring or Hibernate proxies come into the play. This is definitely not JSF/PrimeFaces related. It's basically merely the presenter of the model.

Comment: @BalusC my guess is exactly the same. Spring is most likely creating a proxy object and run "update view procedure" only if detects setters use. I am trying to find out if there is a better way, some magical method that will trigger same action on that object. My goal is to get rid of the setters, replace it with maybe one line solution. It looks like there isn't one :( Thank you every one for trying to help me.